# Intellij debugger stuck on collecting data and showing "null" strings for Array[String] when programming in SCALA

Tags: arrays, string, scala, debugging, intellij-idea

At the moment I am trying to use the IntelliJ debugger to see what is happening with my "Strings" for some weird reason it is not able to read any string. Show "collecting data" or "null" strings.

I have searched online for a solution to this problem but wasn't able to find one. Does anyone have an idea what may cause this?

**My code**

```
def printTest(): String = {
    var pre : Array[String] = ("A * B + C").split(" ")
    var stringToBeReturned : String = ""
    for(x <- 0 until pre.length){
        stringToBeReturned = stringToBeReturned + pre(x)
    }

    return stringToBeReturned
}
```

[image]

**The debugger when hitting the breakpoint:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by downgrading to the 2019 version