# Debugger does not evaluate values scala 2.13

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea

recently I have stared learning scala and I have run into some troubles with debugging,
I am using scala 2.13.11

piece of code that I am running

```
def printTest(): String = {
      val pre: Array[String] = ("A * B + C").split(" ")
      var l = pre.length
      var stringToBeReturned : String = ""
      for(x <- 0 until pre.length){
        stringToBeReturned = stringToBeReturned + pre(x)
      }

      return stringToBeReturned
    }
    var w = printTest()
    println(s"w is equal to $w")
```

then in the console is printed `w is equal to A*B+C`

However when I am trying to debug this program debugger shows like the value is null..
[image]

but the bytes are ok

I have found similar question [Intellij debugger stuck on collecting data and showing "null" strings for Array[String] when programming in SCALA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64188246/intellij-debugger-stuck-on-collecting-data-and-showing-null-strings-for-array) but the answer is to downgrade the ide version and that is something I would want to avoid. Does anyone have had similar problems? Is there a better way to debug scala projects?

Moreover when I stop with the debugger at the line `return stringToBeReturned`
debugger is kinda stuck at "collecting data"
[image]

Comment: What IDE version do you use?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3. However I have restarted my ide and now the debugging works fine? I don't really know what happened...

Comment: Please consider using the latest available version, there were related fixes added.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have updated my ide to the newest version and everyting works fine

Comment: maybe, if you stop using vars and returns, and write idiomatic scala code, many of the IDE quirks would  just go away. These things (vars, returns, procedural loops etc.) are very rarely used in scala, so I would expect the support for them to be much less reliable in the IDE as well.